# Using two steel tongue drums to build a chromatic scale

Tags: drums

Most steel tongue drums aren't chromatic, most are pentatonic, hexatonic, or diatonic. This trait make them easy to play but not very versatile.

[image]

Is it a good solution to have two tongue drums with their key center a tritone apart from each other to build a chromatic scale across the two drums ?

I'm afraid that some detail would make this idea not work in practice. My primary concern would be sympathetic resonance within a tongue drum creating out of key tones. But since I have never played, I don't know whether this would be true or not.

Answer (score 1):

Chromatic steel tongue drums do exist. A google search for "[chromatic steel tongue drum](https://www.google.com/search?q=chromatic%20steel%20tongue%20drum&oq=chromatic%20steel%20tongu&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i60.4240j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" shows at least two makers:

- [Rock Creek Steel Drums](http://www.rockcreeksteeldrums.com/tonguedrums): They make a variety of steel tongue drums, including the "[cycle of fifths](http://www.rockcreeksteeldrums.com/for-sale)", which includes the entire chromatic scale.
- [Zenko](https://metalsounds-shop.com/en/): They make a [two-drum, 17-tone chromatic set](https://metalsounds-shop.com/en/steel-tongue-drum/160-chromatic-ionian-combo-zenko-pack.html) (9 and 8 tones, respectively).

Comment: It does not really answer my question but this answer was useful nonetheless, I did not know this cycle of fifth drum.
The demonstration video of the Zenko Ionian + Combo kinda reassure me on the sympathetic out of tone resonance when playing two very different tongue drum (though I don't really like its sound).